# Função preencher menu dinamicamente

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um resultado que vem após uma consulta no banco de dados. Com este resultado eu faço o menu dinamicamente, quando o usuário tem permissão de visualizar a pagina.
Oque gostaria de saber é se tem a opção de eu melhorar o meu código, ele esta funcionando, mas gostaria de melhorar ele se possível e ter menos linha para compilar.
Este if é apenas o primeiro, para completar todo o menu tenho que repetir ele 50 vezes, que são os itens do menu.
Ja tentei usar o "switch", mas também sem sucesso.

Aqui recebo os dados da consulta do banco de dados

```
$paginas = $pagina->verificaPaginas();
$qtdRow = count($paginas);
```

Resultado do $paginas

```
array(168) { [0]=> array(9) { ["idpagina"]=> string(1) "1" ["url"]=> string(34) "../Acervos/acervoViewCad.class.php" ["descricao"]=> string(9) "CADASTRAR" ["categoria"]=> string(1) "1" ["grupo"]=> string(1) "1" ["acessoid"]=> string(1) "1" ["idlogin"]=> string(1) "1" ["paginaid"]=> string(1) "1" ["visualizar"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(9) { ["idpagina"]=> string(1) "2" ["url"]=> string(37) "../Acervos/acervoViewEditar.class.php" ["descricao"]=> string(7) "ALTERAR" ["categoria"]=> string(1) "1" ["grupo"]=> string(1) "1" ["acessoid"]=> string(1) "2" ["idlogin"]=> string(1) "1" ["paginaid"]=> string(1) "2" ["visualizar"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(9) { ["idpagina"]=> string(1) "3" ["url"]=> string(40) "../Categorias/categoriaViewCad.class.php" ["descricao"]=> string(9) "CADASTRAR" ["categoria"]=> string(1) "2" ["grupo"]=> string(1) "1" ["acessoid"]=> string(1) "3" ["idlogin"]=> string(1) "1" ["paginaid"]=> string(1) "3" ["visualizar"]=> string(1) "1" } [3]=> array(9) { ["idpagina"]=> string(1) "4" ["url"]=> string(43) "../Categorias/categoriaViewEditar.class.php" ["descricao"]=> string(7) "ALTERAR" ["categoria"]=> string(1) "2" ["grupo"]=> string(1) "1" ["acessoid"]=> string(1) "4" ["idlogin"]=> string(1) "1" ["paginaid"]=> string(1) "4" ["visualizar"]=> string(1) "1" } [4]=> array(9) { ["idpagina"]=> string(1) "5" ["url"]=> string(43) "../Fornecedores/fornecedorViewCad.class.php" ["descricao"]=> string(9) "CADASTRAR" ["categoria"]=> string(1) "3" ["grupo"]=> string(1) "1" ["acessoid"]=> string(1) "5" ["idlogin"]=> string(1) "1" ["paginaid"]=> string(1) "5" ["visualizar"]=> string(1) "1" } [5]=> array(9) { ["idpagina"]=> string(1) "6" ["url"]=> string(64) "../Fornecedores/insereMatriculaEditaFornecedorViewGrid.class.php" ["descricao"]=> string(12) "ALTERAR POST" ["categoria"]=> string(1) "3" ["grupo"]=> string(1) "1" ["acessoid"]=> string(1) "6" ["idlogin"]=> string(1) "1" ["paginaid"]=> string(1) "6" ["visualizar"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Aqui é onde faço a montagem do menu dinamicamente

```
 <nav id="menu">
    <ul class="menu"> <!-- Esse é o 1 nivel ou o nivel principal -->
        <?php for ($a = '0';
                   $a < $qtdRow;
                   $a++) { ?>
        <!-- Inicio menu cadastros -->          
    <?php if (($paginas[$a]['grupo'] == 1))  { ?>
        <li><a href="#">CADASTROS</a>
            <ul class="submenu-1"> <!-- Esse é o 1 nivel ou o primeiro Drop Down -->
                <?php for ($a = '0';
                           $a < $qtdRow;
                           $a++) { ?>
            <?php if (($paginas[$a]['categoria'] == 1)) { ?>
                <li><a href="#">ACERVO</a>
                    <ul class="submenu-2"> <!-- Esse é o 2 nivel ou o primeiro Drop Down -->
                        <?php for ($a = '0'; $a < $qtdRow; $a++) { ?>
                            <?php if (($paginas[$a]['categoria'] == 1) && ($paginas[$a]['grupo'] == 1)) { ?>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"
                                       onclick='window.open("<?= $paginas[$a]['url']; ?>", "iframe_a")'><?= $paginas[$a]['descricao']; ?></a>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>

                </li>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
            <!-- Fim menu cadastro-->
            <?php } ?><!-- Fecha contagem -->
```

A seleção do banco vem isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mesmo com WHILE ou SWITCH, acontece a mesma coisa.

Comment: Estes termos CADASTROS e ACERVO, por exemplo, não vem do banco? Poste o código do `$paginas = $pagina->verificaPaginas();`, talvez ajude na formulação de uma ideia. Talvez seguir pela ideia de montar um função para cada nível e ação.

Comment: Bom dia @GnomoEscalate, não estes termos não vem do banco, oque vem do banco é o numero que no caso representa o o grupo e a categoria.
Vc quer o resultado do **$paginas = $pagina->verificaPaginas();**.

Comment: Adicionei parte do resultado @GnomoEscalate.

Comment: Entendi, deu para ver. O que pega é que os termos CADASTROS e ACERVO, por exemplo, são inseridos no seu código manualmente, para facilitar a criação de uma função eles precisariam estar em um banco, array associados ao grupo ou categoria.

Comment: Só que não tenho somente o ACERVO, tenho vários outros que compõe o menu.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.

Bom, pra começar você pode trocar o `for` por `foreach` e apesar deu não ser uma má pratica ou piorar seu código eu recomendo que economize abrir e fechar tags php (`<?php ?>`) para criar código html, tente usar `echo` em alguns casos. Para exemplificar o que quero dizer, vou pegar esse pedaço de código:

```
<?php for ($a = '0'; $a < $qtdRow; $a++) { ?>
                            <?php if (($paginas[$a]['categoria'] == 1) && ($paginas[$a]['grupo'] == 1)) { ?>
                                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"
                                       onclick='window.open("<?= $paginas[$a]['url']; ?>", "iframe_a")'><?= $paginas[$a]['descricao']; ?></a>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
```

Assim:

```
<?php
   foreach($paginas as $dados)
   {
      if($dados['categoria'] == 1 && $dados['grupo'] == 1)
      {
         echo "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"window.open('{$dados['url']}','iframe_a')\">{$dados['descricao']}</a></li>";
      }
   }
?>
```

---

**Agora para a questão do menu.**

Normalmente os menus dinâmicos são de dois níveis e para cada nível uma tabela no banco de dados é criado:

```
Tabela categorias:
id_categoria|nome   |
     1      |Camisas|
     2      |Sapatos|
-----------------------------
Tabela sub_categorias:
id_sub|nome    |id_categoria|
   1  |Cadastro|      1     |
   2  |Alterar |      1     |
   3  |Cadastro|      2     |
   4  |Alterar |      2     |
   5  |Deletar |      2     |
-----------------------------
```

E para percorrer as tabelas cria-se dois métodos, um para listar todos os itens da tabela categoria `listarCategorias()` e outro para listar sub categorias `listarSubCategorias($id_categoria)` esse receberia o id_categoria e só listara os itens de sub_categoria que correspondem a esse id.
O código seria mais ou menos:

```
$categorias = $pagina->listarCategorias();
foreach($categorias as $dados)
{
   echo "<ul>";
      echo "<li><a href='#'>{$dados['nome']}</a>";
         echo "<ul>";
         $sub = $pagina->listarSubCategorias($dados['id_categoria']);
         foreach($sub as $dados2)
         {
            echo "<li><a>{$dados2['nome']}<a></li>";
         }
         echo "</ul>";
   echo "</ul>";
}
```

No seu caso as tabelas teriam mais campos, isso é só um exemplo, caso queira uma resposta mais especifica sugiro que dê mais detalhes sobre como esse menu deve funcionar e o que cada variável significa.

**PS: Tenha em mente que não consigo ver a imagem (por causa do proxy do computador que estou usando para fazer essa resposta).**